# Delete all spaces in list while always returning true?

Tags: prolog

This predicate removes occurrences of a specific element in a list.

```
delMember(_, [], []).
delMember(X, [X|Xs], Y) :-
    delMember(X, Xs, Y).
delMember(X, [T|Xs], [T|Y]) :-
    dif(X, T),
    delMember(X, Xs, Y).
```

I generated a list from a file where each line becomes an element. However, certain lines might be all spaces and should be removed. The above predicate will remove a line that was just one space, but there are two features I need to add to it. Firstly, I need it to remove any element that is all spaces but not just those with only one space. Secondly, if it finds no element that's all spaces, I still need it to return the list unchanged.

Comment: That predicate is dicey. It will remove any element that unifies with the first argument of delMember/3 (not only those with 1 space, and that unification is retained when going down the list), and optimistically keep elements for which it cannot be ascertained that they are "structurally equal" to the first argument of delMember/3 at call time of dif/2. And the clause with the dif/2 comes last. This all looks a bit off.

Answer (score 0):

Create a predicate to verify if an atom is composed only by spaces:

```
spaces(Atom) :-
    atom_chars(Atom, Chars),
    forall(member(Char, Chars), Char == ' ').
```

Example:

```
?- spaces('  a      ').
false.

?- spaces('      ').
true.

?- spaces(' ').
true.
```

Then, use that predicate to filter only those atoms which are not composed only by spaces:

```
del_spaces([], []).
del_spaces([X|Xs], R) :-
    (   spaces(X)
    ->  del_spaces(Xs, R)
    ;   R = [X|Ys],
        del_spaces(Xs, Ys) ).
```

Examples:

```
?- del_spaces([' ', one, 't w o', '   ', three], L).
L = [one, 't w o', three].

?- del_spaces([one, 't w o', three], L).
L = [one, 't w o', three].
```